# Using class.forName in JDBC

Tags: java, class, reflection, jdbc

Following is the code to connect to a MySQL database

```
// This will load the MySQL driver, each DB has its own driver
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  // Setup the connection with the DB
  connect = DriverManager
      .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/feedback?"
          + "user=sqluser&password=sqluserpw");
```

I was learning reflections in java where the class can be obtained using
     Class.forName()

```
 Class c = Class.forName("java.awt.Button");
```

Was the syntax used.

My question is why the MySQL ForName did not needed to be caught in a variable ?

Comment: What do you mean _did not needed to be caught in a Class_?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean why isn't the `Class` object saved into a variable.
Because it wasn't needed. The class only needed to be loaded, the actual `Class` object was superfluous.

Also these days you don't even need to do the `Class.forName()` anymore. The driver will be found from the classpath automatically, if you're using JDBC type 4 (pure java) drivers.

Answer (score 4):

By calling `forName()` you force the class to be *initialized* (which is more than just loading it). In that process some static initializers run, which register that particular class with the JDBC manager code in the JDK. That makes a driver instance available internally to the JDK and it is implicitly used in all later code.

Admittedly, relying on unintuitive Reflection calls is a piece of bad design by the authors of JDBC, but in the early days of Java there were less choices than today and the world of Java wasn't as tough. It was a language which had yet to attract serious adoption.

Comment: I am not sure if using reflection was a bad choice. If you read the older JDBC spec, you get a feeling they were thinking of the driver selection as a runtime choice rather than a design/development time choice. And for a runtime choice, reflection (either directly or hidden away behind an abstraction like the JDBC 4.0 autoloading) is the only real option. It also promotes the use of the API rather than concrete classes.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Yes, I am commenting only on the approach with the bare reflective call and relying on class initialization to register the driver class, which is unintuitive and continues to confuse beginners to this day.